# verifytext in Selenium IDE script failing in IE even when it should be passing

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

Got a Selenium IDE script recorded and being played back using Selenium Server in -htmlSuite mode.It is supposed to put the type the User Name, Password and Domain then click Login. After logging in, at one corner, it should show UserName @ Domain. I have a verifyText for this. When I ran the script in Firefox, it is working correctly, but in IE, it keeps failing - giving me an error message Actual value 'UserName @ Domain' did not match 'UserName @ Domain'. I tried also assert and same thing. Is this a bug in Selenium or something?

Answer (score 1):

You should try using [`waitForText`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#storeText), [`waitForElementPresent`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#storeElementPresent) or [`waitForTextPresent`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#storeTextPresent) commands, depending on your specific need.

The reason being that usually, when any text is created by a script on/after the page load, Selenium doesn't know about it - it can't possibly wait for every script to finish, because there's a lot of scripts that never finish and run forever. Therefore, you need to wait for your specific elements to appear before you can assert them.

Comment: Hi Slanec, I also tried that. I even put a pause before it. Same thing. I think the element is present when it runs the command as it is getting an Actual value and not timing out. Even the Actual value it gets is correct - it just marks the step as Fail instead of Pass. And again, it happens only in IE and works fine with Firefox.

Comment: A-ha. I guess that in that case, we don't have sufficient information. It's (almost) definitely not a bug in Selenium, there are hundreds of people using the same API every day. Could you post the html code of the element containing the text? I suspect some HTML escape entities to play with the result...

Comment: Sorry been awfully busy on my other projects. I'll go check on the HTML code and get back to you guys. Curious thing though, it works perfectly fine in Firefox, but not in IE. That's the reason I thought it was a bug. Another thing I thought of now is to try it also in Webdriver as well and see if I still have issues.